# Difference between values in while loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I am trying to compute the differences between array values in PHP in a while loop.
Initially I was using a foreach loop using (next) and (prev) but it didn't seem to work very well.

What I am trying now actually works but the problem is the value that is calculated should actually appear on the next line of the table.
Here is the table and HTML:

```
        <table table id="meter_entries" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive"><thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Company Code</th>
                <th>Oil Height</th>
                <th>Water Height</th>
                <th>Total Volume</th>
                <th>Difference</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php 
            $s = $stock_automatic; $i=0; $count = count($s); 
            while($i < $count){ 
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $s[$i]['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s[$i]['timess']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s[$i]['company_code']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s[$i]['oil_height']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s[$i]['water_height']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s[$i]['total_volume']; ?></td>
                <td><?php $oldvol = $s[$i-1]['total_volume']; $currvol = $s[$i]['total_volume'];  $diff =  $oldvol - $currvol; echo $diff; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url('stock_automatic/edit/'.$s[$i]['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</a> 
                    <a href="<?php echo site_url('stock_automatic/remove/'.$s[$i]['id']); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php 
               $i++; 
            } 
            ?>
        </table>
```

Here is the output:
[image: Table]

Comment: *the value that is calculated should actually appear on the next line of the table*. You mean i.e. for ID 39, you should have that line and then on the next line you should have 1 cell with only the difference?

Comment: if you look at ID 52 the total volume is 32530.40, ID 53 has a total volume of 45136.60 but the difference appearing on line ID 52 should actually appear on the row of ID 53. to show that from 52 -> 53 there was a difference of 12606.2

Comment: `$oldvol = $s[$i-1]['total_volume']` is that working? since on first iteration you will aasign to `$oldvol = $s[-1]['total_volume']`

Comment: Yeah, was just about to ask that as well. This should throw errors.

Comment: I actually had an if statement... if($i = 0){ echo $i;} else {  THE CODE I HAVE ABOVE}. I took it out for stackoverflow as I was still working on it

Comment: I can see from your picture that you probably have datatables. What i think is happening is that the ordering that datatables enforces is actually reverse than the `$s` arrays order. Can you deactivate datatables and echo the table again to see how the original output is before datatables ordering?

Comment: I am seriously wondering what is going on, copying your example with some dummy data works perfectly fine. Note that I have changed `$diff =  $currvol - $oldvol` but that is not the problem. https://3v4l.org/GGYko

Comment: @Loek it seems the problem is with datatables indeeed because it does actually work without datatables. Hmmm

Comment: Ah cool. Good luck with debugging that :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is that you are using datatables and your array `$s` is actually ordered the opposite way than it is displayed in your example.

To get the correct values you should change your code to the following

```
<?php if ($i==$count-1){
    echo '0';
}
else { 
    $oldvol = $s[$i+1]['total_volume']; $currvol = $s[$i]['total_volume'];  
    $diff =  $currvol - $oldvol; echo $diff;
} ?>
```